# react native ios project appdelegate.m to appdelegate.swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I've converted the project from objective-c to swift, so instead of appdelegate.m and h and main.h i have only appdelegate.swift with objective-c bridging header.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var bridge: RCTBridge!

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    var jsCodeLocation: NSURL?
    jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURLForBundleRoot("index.ios", fallbackResource: nil)
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL:jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "MyApp", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions:launchOptions)

    self.bridge = rootView.bridge

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()

    rootViewController.view = rootView

    self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }

  func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return RCTLinkingManager.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
  }

}
```

Objective-c bridging header :

```
#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"
#import "RCTLinkingManager.h"
#import "CodePush.h"
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "RCTUtils.h"
#import "RCTConvert.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"
```

Unfortunately it throws error :

```
2016-11-08 16:02:30.393 [fatal][tid:main] No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have embedded a JS bundle in your application bundle.unsanitizedScriptURLString:((null))
2016-11-08 16:02:30.404 MyApp[76794:1727873] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have embedded a JS bundle in your application bundle.unsanitizedScriptURLString:((null))', reason: 'No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have embed...'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i have also encountered with the same issue when i change the build configuration to production.Did you solve this problem?